# Сортировка списка Python по нескольким параметрам

Tags: python

У меня есть список :
`list1 = ['black 2340 1743', 'black 3948 2011', 'black 396 1739', 'black 5080 463', 'black 5864 2059']`
Мне необходимо отсортировать сначала по алфавитному порядку первый элемент(цвет), если он повторяется, отсортировать по 3 параметру в порядке возрастания, а если и он повторяется, то отсортировать по 2 парамету в порядке возрастания. Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте функцию `sorted` с параметром `key` [[1]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) и [[2]](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

```py
array = ['black 2340 1743', 'black 3948 2011', 'black 396 1739', 'black 5080 463', 'black 5864 2059']

def key(element):
    color, x, y = element.split()
    return (color, int(y), int(x))

print(sorted(array, key=key))
# ['black 5080 463', 'black 396 1739', 'black 2340 1743', 'black 3948 2011', 'black 5864 2059']
```

Answer (score 0):

Разбейте каждую строку на список из 3x строк. Далее отсоритруйте стандартным методом `sort()` или фунцией `sorted()`. Python автоматически отсортирует всё как вам надо.

```
a = ['black 2340 1743', 'black 3948 2011', 'black 396 1739', 'black 5080 463', 'black 5864 2059']

#разделяем строки
for in range(0, len(a)): a[i] = a[i].split()

#сортируем
a.sort()
```

Если вам надо будет получить из массива строку под номером i, используйте:

```
' '.join(a[i])
```

**P.s.**
Работать это будет потому, что одно число будет больше другого если оно больше в алфовитном порядке